# Are there non-obvious cases where (!x || x) can evaluate to false in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just got handed down an older JavaScript project (the original devs already left the company and are not available). Recently I found a condition like this:

```js
const xPermanent = await Promise(/* some call to a Sequelize 5.8.x object */)
const xMulti = await Promise(/* some call to a Sequelize 5.8.x object */)

// lots of code which occasionally checks but never modifies xMulti

if (xPermanent && (!xMulti || xMulti)) {
```

I'm no expert in Javascript. As I understand, this always evaluates to `true` if `xPermanent` is true. Are there any edge cases in which this could evaluate to `false` other than `xPermanent` being `false`?

My normal understanding of logic would say, that I can remove the second part of the condition, but I also heard Javascript does weird things evaluating objects sometimes...

Comment: "I can fly or I can't fly". Truest possible statement. It doesn't get any more true than that. `(!xMulti || xMulti)` can't be false, it's logically impossible.

Comment: (!x || x) seems like a universal TRUTH to me...you really needed acknowledgement from us about it?

Comment: @Ergis  It's maybe not such a bad idea asking, as some things can sometimes seem a bit odd,.  eg.  `NaN === NaN` evaluates to `false`,. instead you need to use `Number.isNaN(n)`

Answer (score 2):

The test for the xMulti variable is completely irrelevant. It coerces xMulti into a truthy or falsey value, and says "pass this part of the test if it is true or false". Since a boolean can only be true or false, logic dictates that `(!xMulti || xMulti)` is superfluous.

At one time there might have been different logic, but as it stands, remove that code with prejudice.

A simple test for `if (xPermanent)` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of Javascript :)

You are looking for an edge case, if xMulti is mutable, then it could be false.  eg. Proxy's & getters allow mutation.

The below is an example using a getter, of course this is just plain stupid code, but JS allows you to do these sort of things.. :)

Looking at your code though, it looks like your OK, as those consts are not getters or proxys.

```js
let x = 1;

class Silly {
  get xMulti() { return x--; }
}

with (new Silly()) {
  console.log(`true && (!xMulti || xMulti)`);
  if (true && (!xMulti || xMulti)) {
    console.log(`It's true`);
  } else {
    console.log(`It's false`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Code like this makes me simultaneously love and hate JavaScript. Maybe rename `Silly` to `WTF` and [post it here](https://wtfjs.com/)?

Comment: @GregBurghardt  Yeah, with great power comes great responsibility, but I don't think I'd have it any other way... :)  Saying that if any of our coders did this sort of code, I might need to have a stern word with them.   ps: Yes, I don't use `with` in real code either.. :)

Comment: I mean, it's not much different from C# with `class Silly { private bool _internal = false; public bool xMulti { get => _internal = !internal; } }` Allowing dynamic getters leads to the same situation. Heck, you don't even need dynamic getters - Java doesn't have them but you can have a simple `class Silly { public boolean xMulti = true; }` and launch a separate thread that keeps flipping it randomly, so it might change between two reads. JS is not really as crazy here.

Comment: @VLAZ  That's true, most languages allow Silly things, and yes multi-threading is a different story, even incrementing a number can cause all hell to break loose, say the word critical section / mutex and it sends shivers down my spine, these days even trivial multi-threading I'd rather IPC it.   When I have some time, I'll maybe have a dabble with Rust, as it's borrow architecture is meant to prevent most MT issues.

Comment: [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) is deprecated—thank god, right?—but nice to know about [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Comment: Might as well have used `Object.defineProperty` on `globalThis`.